# Is the histogram that's shown on a DSLR different from the histogram of the same image shown in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, histogram, ettr

I was taking some images and experimenting with the ETTR approach. I was trying to take pictures with the exposure setting that would have the right end of the histogram just touching the border on the right.
But the histogram shown in DSLR and the one of the same image in Lightroom seem to be different in terms of whether the rightmost end is touching the border or not.

Is this normal? Why does it happen? Which one is more accurate?

I used a Nikon d5600. Also, i am shooting in RAW, if that makes a difference.
Also i am not talking about the LR histogram after making adjustments. That would obviously be different. I am talking about the in camera histogram vs the histogram in LR BEFORE making any LR adjustments

Comment: Lightroom's histogram seems to be the current JPEG conversion.  At least if I move the sliders in the develop window the histogram changes.

Comment: @RossMillikan I know that, but that is not the issue, s ince i am looking at the histograms BEFORE having made any adjustments yet,

Comment: It seems on might assume the histograms give the distribution of raw data, which would not change with adjustments.  The histograms before the shot would be the raw data taken from reading the sensor.  This shows they are not.

Answer (score 7):

There are many reasons why they may be different.

- Many cameras will show luminance histogram clipping if any one of the color channels is clipped.
- Many cameras will show a color channel as clipped at a level of around 245-250 (i.e. early).
- Some camera's histograms just lie pretty badly (my D800 did)...
- The camera's histogram is based on the camera processed jpeg and is highly unlikely to match the raw file data (if recording/editing raw).

The histogram in LR is almost certainly more accurate than the one in your camera.

---

Edit

And interestingly, LR's histogram may not match the camera's histogram for a jpeg image either (reasons 1-3 above).

Here is a D850 jpeg image review on the camera.

[image]

It shows all three channels and the combined luminance as touching the right side (clipping) and the highlight warning shows a large area on the upper chest as clipped for all four (R/G/B/L).

[image]

This is the same jpeg w/o any edits in LR.

[image]

The histogram doesn't show any luminance clipping (short of right edge), and if I hold alt while selecting the exposure slider it shows me that the small clipping warnings are for the blue channel only.

And the raw file histogram looks somewhat different as well (as expected).
You can do some things so that the camera histogram(s) and image review more closely matches the raw file histogram(s); at the expense of less usable jpegs SOOC. I use the "neutral" camera profile with reduced contrast (minimum) and brightness (-1) settings so the image review is closer to a raw image in LR with the same "neutral" profile applied. You can also go down the path of using uni-wb in camera; for totally useless jpegs, a lot of hassle, and a bit better histogram match.

But none of that is absolutely necessary... all you really need is to develop a good idea of the difference between what your camera typically shows vs the same raw/jpeg file opened with defaults (and it's highlight recoverability).

---

Many who shoot ETTR record raw files; push the in-camera histogram to where it is just showing clipping (slightly climbing right side; at least touching), and rely on the ~1stop of recovery capability. But you have to experiment with your camera to know how far you can push it. Also, do not ETTR by increasing the ISO... there's no point to doing that (ISO is not light/exposure/data).

Comment: " _The camera's histogram is based on the camera processed jpeg and is highly unlikely to match the raw file data (if recording/editing raw)._ " If this is true, then indeed it seems like the camera histogram is less accurate than the one in LR.

Comment: The camera's jpg is based on what you set in-camera before taking the photo. The one in Lr is a total guess. That, in my book, makes the camera's more accurate than Lr's.

Comment: @silverrahul Neither is necessarily more or less accurate than the other. They just reflect the results of two different interpretations of the same raw data. Neither is a representation of the linear, unprocessed values in the raw file. Both are representations of the raw data converted to one of a near countless number of possible interpretations of the raw data.

Comment: @MichaelC okay, so when i am trying to use the histogram as a guide to avoid highlight clipping, which one should i follow ? Surely from what you are saying, the LR histogram is a more accurate guide for this purpose ?

Comment: Well, if you can see the LR histogram while you're shooting, then by all means use it to adjust exposure. But it will only be more accurate if you've already adjusted LR to your final desired settings, because when you make an adjustment in LR, that change is reflected in the histogram LR displays based upon the resulting image now displayed on your screen that is different from the image displayed before you made that adjustment.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I can see where the camera's histogram is more accurate for the camera generated jpeg. But not much for the ETTR technique with raw files.

Comment: @StevenKersting " _all you really need is to develop a good idea of the difference between what your camera typically shows vs the same raw file opened with defaults_ " I can SEE the difference between what camera histogram shows and what the same raw file opened in LR with defaults shows, because i am shooting tethered. Which is why i know what each histogram is showing. The question then is which histogram to rely on to ensure good ETTR and avoid highlight clipping. From your answer, i assume i should rely on the LR histogram, am i correct ?

Comment: @MichaelC " _if you can see the LR histogram while you're shooting, then by all means use it to adjust exposure_ " I can see it , i am shooting tethered.


" _But it will only be more accurate if you've already adjusted LR to your final desired settings, because when you make an adjustment in LR, that change is reflected in the histogram LR_ "
Shouldn't this be the other way round ? Shouldnt it be more accurate when i HAVEN'T made any adjustments ? Once i make adjustments, the histogram would change to reflect those adjustments.

Comment: @StevenKersting Also, one maybe stupid question regarding the D850 jpeg image review histogram photo that you posted.

" _It shows all three channels and the combined luminance as touching the right side (clipping)_ "
But all 3 channels and the combined one are nowhere near the right side, they are just touching the middle line, only green is slightly crossing over to the right of middle line, with plenty more space on the right of it ? Is the middle line the one it should be touching or the rightmost border is the one it should be touching ?

Comment: @silverrahul, the height of a histogram is the number of pixels at that exposure. On each of the camera histograms there is a line across the bottom from near the left edge and touching the right edge indicating some pixels at all of those exposure values... it's probably easiest to see in the green histogram and larger image (click on it).

Comment: @silverrahul, if shooting tethered into LR then I would definitely trust it's histograms... I wouldn't even bother looking at the in-camera review. But also be aware of the default edits being applied and how they affect the display (e.g. try using the camera neutral or flat profiles in LR).

Comment: @silverrahul Remember (we've told you this several times already), the first thing you see when you open a raw file in LR, or any other raw conversion app, is NOT **"THE raw image**. *There's no such thing.* It is one of countless possible interpretation s of the data in the raw file. There is no *most accurate* interpretation of raw image data. There is only *the particular interpretation you are currently looking at*. Your adjustments are neither any more nor any less legitimate/accurate/pure/authentic/"real" than the default settings used when the file was first opened.

Comment: If you're shooting to keep highlights just under clipping, then shoot to have them just under clipping *with the settings you want to use applied*.

Comment: @MichaelC " _If you're shooting to keep highlights just under clipping, then shoot to have them just under clipping with the settings you want to use applied_ "  By settings, do you mean exposure settings or the adjustments in LR ? If you mean adjustments in LR, isn't the whole point of ETTR supposed to be to have highlights just under clipping, BEFORE making any adjustments ? And if you mean exposure  settings, then which histogram do i refer to , while trying to keep the highlights just under clipping? I get that neither is "real" but still i should use one rather than use neither, right ?

Comment: @StevenKersting " _Also, do not ETTR by increasing the ISO... there's no point to doing that_ " I think there can be exceptions to this rule. While this is true in general, in my specific case, i was taking pictures of stars in sky. So, my aperture was at the maximum size i.e. F3.5, my shutter was also at the slowest possible without blurring the stars. So, at that point, the only thing left to increase exposure is ISO. And it definitely gets better results than ones with lower ISO, with the same aperture and shutter setting.

Comment: @silverrahul "By settings, do you mean exposure settings or the adjustments in LR?" Both. "... isn't the whole point of ETTR supposed to be to have highlights just under clipping, BEFORE making any adjustments?" Generally, the point of ETTR is to expose the shadows as brightly as possible without clipping highlights, then raising *the shadows* in post (and the mids either way) while leaving the highlights just beneath clipping. YMMV. "... then which histogram do I refer to?" Again: **Well, if you can see the LR histogram while you're shooting, then by all means use it to adjust exposure.**

Comment: " _if you can see the LR histogram while you're shooting, then by all means use it to adjust exposure_ " Cool. This is the definitive answer to the question i wanted to know. I should have highlighted that part in the question body.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this normal?

Yes, this is to be expected.

> Why does it happen?

The JPEG preview image produced by the camera (when saving raw data) is one among a near countless possible interpretations of the raw data. The in-camera histogram is based upon the JPEG preview.

The image displayed on your screen when LR opens a raw file is one among a near countless possible interpretations of the raw data. The histogram displayed by LR is based on the current processed interpretation of the raw data that is displayed on your monitor.

They're not the same interpretation, therefore they won't have the same histogram.

> Which one is more accurate?

Neither is necessarily more or less accurate than the other. They just reflect the results of two different interpretations of the same raw data. Neither is a representation of the linear, unprocessed values in the raw file. Both are representations of two different interpretations among a near countless number of possible interpretations of the raw data.

Comment: Cameras display histograms in Live View when there is no Jpg.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens the histogram is not actually based on the JPEG, it's based on the currently displayed bitmap, from whatever source.

Comment: The vast majority of cameras display histograms in LV that are based on what a JPEG produced from the current settings would look like. The distinction is immaterial when talking about still images that *have already been shot*.

Answer (score 3):

They're both "correct" for a given value of "correct".

The one in the camera knows the formula of the conversion between the RAW file & the presented image. Lightroom has only guesswork, a reverse-engineered interpretation of what Nikon intended for those settings on that RAW file.

So, both are 'correct' but each is measuring something different.

If you want to see what Nikon thinks it ought to look like, use ViewNX-i or the newer NX Studio.

Comment: The one in LR is based upon the settings that result in the interpretation of the raw data currently displayed on the screen. It's not based upon any guess about what the histogram of a Nikon in-camera jpeg looks like (unless one has opened an in-camera produced JPEG in LR). The one in the camera is based upon either the JPEG (if the image was saved as JPEG) or JPEG preview (if the raw file was saved).

Comment: @MichaelC - so, it's based on guesswork, as I said, not upon anything decided by the photographer in-camera. I doubt we will ever agree on this, but I simply hate what Lr does to my photos. I just will not use it, precisely because of that.

Comment: It's not based on any amount of guesswork. Both histograms are based upon a specific interpretation: The one that is currently being displayed, either on the camera's display or on the computer's display.

Comment: @MichaelC - the image itself is total guesswork, so the histogram is relevant only to that poor interpretation of what the camera was set to. That makes it less use than a chocolate fireplace, imo.

Comment: The histogram is not the image, it is an empirical representation of an image. The image may be a guess as to what the photographer ultimately wants to end up with (which can be just as true for the in-camera JPEG preview as it is for the initial interpretation displayed by LR), but the histogram is not a guess about the brightness levels of whatever the displayed image looks like. You seem to be arguing that the only possible "correct" image from a raw file is the JPEG preview produced in camera. If that is the case, then why not just save straight to JPEG and do no further editing at all?

Comment: Sometimes the camera does not have the capability to be set to do what the photographer desires to do with the raw data. Very few cameras, for instance, have controls to adjust HSL for eight independent colors. If the photographer desires to use HSL adjustments, then the camera is incapable of producing the photographer's intent. I often adjust brightness in 1/6 stop or finer increments in post. I've never had a camera with 1/6 stop steps for Tv, Av, or ISO.

Comment: "why not just save straight to JPEG" is a non-sequitur, a post hoc ergo propter hoc argument. I don't go straight to jpg because I want to edit further from that start point. if I open photos in Lr it takes me 15 minutes to even arrive at that start point, because it has no clue what the camera's setting were. [Look at the bird picture above, nothing like!]

Comment: You can do it once and save those settings. It then takes about 2-3 clicks to apply the same settings to every image in a folder, or however many of those images you have selected to apply that "preset".

Comment: @Tetsujin I get that neither is 100% accurate or real, but isn't the whole point of ETTR is to try to dial in the exposure settings which have the highlights just clipping ? And to figure out that exposure setting, histogram is surely a valuable tool ? Given that this is the case. i have a choice which histogram to use, the in camera one of the image captured or the LR one of the image captured. Which should i use, that is the point of my question

Answer (score 1):

A [histogram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) displays the frequency at which values fall into an arbitrary set of ranges.

Arbitrary in the sense that two histograms of the same data can divide a range possible values into a different quantity of ranges.

For example, one histogram might divide the possible values of the blue channel into 10 ranges and another might divide the same possible values into 100 ranges.

How many ranges to use is entirely dependent on intent. Lightroom’s histogram cannot prevent over exposure (tethering excepted). It is too late. The camera histogram cannot prevent clipping in post processing (in-camera edits excepted). It is too soon.

Ultimately, the photographer just has to learn from experience what the histogram in each tool means.

Comment: " _Lightroom’s histogram cannot prevent over exposure (tethering excepted)._ " Interesting, you should mention that. I WAS using tethering with laptop. This is why i had the option to compare both the histograms as soon as i took the capture and noticed the difference.